# how to use a function with Boolean? return type in an if statement in Kotlin

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I'm using methods (for example the method containsKey of MutableList) that returns a true false.
Since the function is written in java, Kotlin refers to return type as Boolean? and this the reason i'm getting a compilation error: "Required: Boolean, Found: Boolean?".
I must say in some case (don't know why) using the method is ok and sometimes it return the error above.
Can someone guess what is the reason?

My code:

```kotlin
val gamesPerCountriesMap = mutableMapOf<String,MutableMap<Long, List<AllScoresGameObj>>>()

if (countryName != null  && countryName != "" && !gamesPerCountriesMap.containsKey(countryName))
{
    gamesPerCountriesMap.put(countryName, mutableMapOf<Long,List<AllScoresGameObj>>())
}

if (!gamesPerCountriesMap.get(countryName)?.containsKey(competitionId))
{
    gamesPerCountriesMap.get(countryName)?.put(competitionId, listOf<AllScoresGameObj>())
}
```

First if is compiled the second one make the error:

> Only safe (?.) or non-null asserted (!!.) calls are allowed on a nullable receiver of type Boolean?

if I remove the **!** in the beginning of the second if i will different error:

> Type mismatch: inferred type is Boolean? but Boolean was expected

After reading all the suggestion i wrote the following code:

```kotlin
gamesPerCountriesMap.get(countryName)?.let {
    if (!gamesPerCountriesMap.containsKey(it))
    {
        gamesPerCountriesMap.get(countryName)?.put(competitionId, listOf<AllScoresGameObj>())
    }
}
```

What do you think?

Comment: Show code snippet

Comment: Done two seconds ago  :)

Comment: Error snippet, the code where u r getting this boolean error point that out as well

Comment: Added two possible snippest errors

Comment: I found the solution, but i don't know why and how it solves the problem... If i adds *a == false* both error disappears

Comment: `== false` takes care of the case where the `Boolean` is `null`.

Comment: Your Java code datatypes can have null values but Kotlin doesn't allow null values by default. But since your Java code can allow null value, your Kotlin code will have to be handled to accept null values. In your Java code look after to not send a null value as return data that will fix this.

Comment: @PrajwalWaingankar, Yes but unfortunately there are a lot of java code that is core java that i can't do nothing about it

Comment: How does == false takes care of the case where the Boolean is null? how null can be compared to false?

Answer (score 0):

You have to take care of the nullable

```
mutableMapOf<String?, MutableMap...
```

That means the keys can be a null String

If the `countryName` is a field, then

```
countryName?.let {
   //your validation here
}
```

Fields can be changed so compiler doesn't know if it nullable or not.

or

```
val safeName = countryName ?: return
```

Comment: the issue isn't related to containsKey who can return a *Boolean?*  ?  Because the following code still has an error:
   countryName?.let {
                                if (!gamesPerCountriesMap.get(countryName)?.containsKey(competitionId))
                            }

I think that the issue related to the fact that *get* method can return null
let can be used in the following way (and it is work):
gamesPerCountriesMap.get(countryName)?.let {
                                if (!gamesPerCountriesMap.containsKey(it))

Answer (score 0):

Basically in the Java, Boolean is an object type. It has 3 possible values: true, false, and null. Since kotlin have null safety feature, using `?` in object type, like Boolean?, that's why it's asking you to make sure that the data isn't null. So for your code:

```
 if (!gamesPerCountriesMap.get(countryName)?.containsKey(competitionId))
                        {
                            gamesPerCountriesMap.get(countryName)?.put(competitionId, listOf<AllScoresGameObj>())
                        }
```

It checks if the `get` method returning null or not, if it's not, then it proceed to the next function `containsKey`. If it's null, then it's pass the if statement. For the non-null asserted, it's force the `Boolean?` data type into the `Boolean`. This can be use if you're sure that the data must not be null, else it'll break your program, because you're accessing function in a null data. So it depends on your choice, you can use `?` or `!!` if you sure it's not null.

Comment: how to use the *?*

Comment: Like the snippet code above, `gamesPerCountriesMap.get(countryName)?.put(competitionId, listOf<AllScoresGameObj>())`. It means, if this `gamesPerCountriesMap.get(countryName)` return not null value, it proceed to the put method, else it stop there.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (!gamesPerCountriesMap.get(countryName)?.containsKey(competitionId))
```

will check if the item is true, false or null. The "if" statement requires true or false. This is why you see "Type mismatch: inferred type is Boolean? but Boolean was expected"

```
if (gamesPerCountriesMap.get(countryName) == null || !gamesPerCountriesMap.get(countryName)!!.containsKey(competitionId))
```

if the item is null, or if not null but also does not contain competitionID, then do this, so thats what you want to use.

Edit:

You also want to allow the map to contain a null value like this:

```
val gamesPerCountriesMap = mutableMapOf<String,MutableMap<Long, List<AllScoresGameObj>>?>()
```

the "?" at the end allows the nested MutableMap to be null.

Comment: Why do you say : "*will return false if the first side is null, so thats what you want to use.*". What is order of the check?if get return null, then null is checked against true and return false and then the *!* will change all the if to true. Isn't it?

Comment: The if statement requires a true or false and cannot be determined with null. "Type mismatch: inferred type is Boolean? but Boolean was expected". You are giving it a Boolean? but it requires a Boolean. Adding the "== true" to it will turn it into a boolean, because if you get null, null does not equal true, so it will return false.

Comment: don't you forget the *!* in your explanation. it will make the false to true

Comment: Oh yea, I see sorry. I fixed it, you just need to add brackets. if (!(gamesPerCountriesMap.get(countryName)?.containsKey(competitionId) == true))

Comment: How does it help? still, if *get* method returns null, then null is compare to true and all the expression (gamesPerCountriesMap.get(countryName)?.containsKey(competitionId) == true) is false. Then *!* on it, will make it to true

Comment: Right again, third times the charm? if (gamesPerCountriesMap.get(countryName) == null || !gamesPerCountriesMap.get(countryName)!!.containsKey(competitionId))

Comment: but if the country name is null, do you think that the all expression should be true? i think that in this case it should be false

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/224750/discussion-between-peter-dolman-and-eitanos30).

Answer (score 0):

You can reduce it like:

```kotlin
if (!countryName.isNullOrEmpty()) {
    gamesPerCountriesMap.getOrPut(countryName) { mutableMapOf<Long,List<AllScoresGameObj>>() }
}

gamesPerCountriesMap[countryName]!!.getOrPut(competitionId) { listOf<AllScoresGameObj>() }
```